# Django, accessing model methods

Tags: python, django

In the Django documentation, they recommend writing business logic in Model.

How do the View layer or queryset access the methods in Model ?

As per example in documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/)

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()

    def baby_boomer_status(self):
        "Returns the person's baby-boomer status."
        import datetime
        if self.birth_date < datetime.date(1945, 8, 1):
            return "Pre-boomer"
        elif self.birth_date < datetime.date(1965, 1, 1):
            return "Baby boomer"
        else:
            return "Post-boomer"
```

How do view layer access the `baby_boomer_status` ?

I have a little experienced in Django development but I used to write logics in View itself.

Comment: what exactly is unclear, it is python instance method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by simply calling function. For example,

```
>>> from .models import Person
>>> person = Person.objects.get(id=1) # Remember getting the person object
>>> person.baby_boomer_status()
```

You have to first get person object otherwise, it will return function itself, e.g

```
>>> from .models import Person
>>> person.baby_boomer_status()
>>> <function AppName.models.Person.baby_boomer_status(self)>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the method on the person instance:

```
person = Person.objects.get(id=1)
print(person.baby_boomer_status())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over QuerySet and call the model method as

```
for person in Person.objects.all():
    print(person.baby_boomer_status())
```

If you have a single object, just call the method directly as,

```
print(Person.objects.get(pk=123).baby_boomer_status())
```